# How to create an iterable key->value structure in Solidity?

Tags: dapp-development, mapping, struct

I am trying to create a framework for users to offer generic goods for sale. For example, a single generic item (a Gizmo) might have 14 people selling it for different prices and from different parts of the world. To enable this, I need to manage a list of prices, kept in storage, that can be queried by a web3.js-driven frontend.

Something like a mapping would be best:

```
uint productId;  // Set automatically for each product
uint memberId;  // Set automatically at join
uint price;  // Prices are in US cents

/* (productId => (memberId => price)) */
mapping (uint => mapping (uint => uint)) priceLedgers;

/* Pseudo-JavaScript below */
for (var i=0, i < priceLedgers[productId].length, i++) {
    // List of members with their prices here.
}
```

Maybe aonther way to explain what I am trying to do is with Python.

```
priceOffers = {}
priceOffers[1] = 234
priceOffers[45] = 99392
priceOffers[23] = 111

>>> priceOffers
{1: 234, 45: 99392, 23: 111}

>>> for key, value in priceOffers.iteritems():
    print(key, value)
(1, 234)
(45,99392)
(23, 111)

productId = 34
priceLedgers = {}
priceLedgers[34] = priceOffers
```

Is this possible in Solidity?

Comment: Do you actually need a mapping here? It seems like a list of structs would serve you just as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just store the index of the mapping in an array.

```
uint[] indexes;
mapping (uint => uint) example;

function add(uint x){
  example[indexes.length] = x;
 indexes.push(indexes.length);
}
```

Then just iterate over the array index as key.

if you want custom unordered keys, it's the same. You would just need to pass the key in the add function

```
function add(uint data,uint index){
  example[index] = data;
  indexes.push(index);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is implementation of such structure:
https://github.com/chriseth/solidity-examples/blob/master/iterable_mapping.sol

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution that will probably work.

```
/* Basic arrays of objects */
Product[] products;
Member[] members;  // `Member` defined elsewhere

/* Custom data types for my objects */
struct Product {
    string name;  // Product’s display name
    Offer[] priceList;  // An array of prices – see struct below.
    uint dateAdded;  // Unix timestamp for when product was added
}

// This is a type that sets a seller’s price for a product
stuct Offer {
    uint memberId;  // Seller’s memberId
    uint priceTag;  // Price seller will take for 1 quantity in US cents
}
```

Pseudo-JavaScript:

```
/* Get all sellers and prices */
for (var i=0, i < products[productId].priceList.length, i++) {
    memberId = products[productId].priceList[i].memberId

    var member = members[memberId]
    var price = products[productId].priceList[i].priceTag
}

/* Get one seller's price */
var myProduct;
var memberToFind = 4;
var membersPrice;
for (var i=0, i < products[productId].priceList.length, i++) {
    if (products[productId].priceList[i].memberId == memberToFind) {
        membersPrice = products[productId].priceList[i].price;
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Can anyone find a better way?